# Java timer and scalability

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, timer, scalability

I have scoured through online posts that grudginly but satisfactorily answer two questions I have.

1. How do you execute a timer inside a java loop
2. How many threads can a single jvm instance handle

So in the context of the above two questions, it's pretty obvious that (without much tinkering) a jvm with 4GB RAM will handle something below 10k threads. There's all this stuff about asynchronous event-based  frameworks which is ok in the context where a thread's data is not extremely important across other threads. But what if the data in a timer thread (inside a loop) is important to the other 10k requests/sec?

Real life situation I can think of is an online questionnaire. Lets say you are having 5 questionnaires. Each questionnaire has 10 questions. You anticipate that you will have 20000 respondents to each questionnaire. All the questionnaires begin at the same time. Each question takes a minute before the other one shows up (because u want to ensure objectivity, for instance)

That means that per second, you would have to expect to handle at least 20000 threads, if each respondent starts 1/20th of a second apart. That's because each request has to sustain it's data beyond a second for the next request to use.

How on earth would you scale up to say 100k users given the same context? If anything is not clear, ask so that I can clarify.

Comment: What's the problem for 1? You write function you call in timerTask's `run()` method, and you can call it in loop

Comment: Timers can easily be aggregated and handles asynchronously, without all these extra threads - see [util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), which supports 'an unlimited number of timers' on a single thread. Also, not sure how the 'real life' example fits.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the thread-per-task execution model, it does not scale well.

You can use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead.

In general I would recommend taking a broad look at the standard library so you know which tools are available instead of trying to build everything from scratch.